# Generic interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface, generic-interface

Here is my code

```
public interface ITranslator<E, R>
{       
    E ToEntity<T>(R record);
}

class Gens : ITranslator<string, int>
{
    #region ITranslator<string,int> Members

    public string ToEntity<MyOtherClass>(int record)
    {
        return record.ToString();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When I compile this, I get an error `Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type`

Why is that I cannot have `ToEntity<MyOtherClass>` but can only have `ToEntity<T>` ??

Edit: what is `MyOtherClass` doing ? I am converting between entities(POCOs equivalent of Entity framework) and record(Object returned by the framework)  for multiple tables/classes. So I would want to use this to do my class specific conversion

Comment: @Ram, you need to tell us: how is `MyOtherClass` supposed to be involved in your method `Gens.ToEntity`? From the code it's not clear at all. If we knew your intention behind it, we could probably offer some more useful feedback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your interface has a generic `ToEntity<T>` method that you've made non-generic in your implementation class `Gens` as `ToEntity<MyOtherClass>`. (A *generic* method could take any type parameter, possibly given certain constraints on `T`. Your `Gens` class is trying to provide a definition for `ToEntity` *only for the type parameter `MyOtherClass`*, which defeats the purpose of generics.)

In your code example, it's unclear how your `Gens` class is trying to use the `MyOtherClass` type; it's certainly not involved in the logic of `ToEntity`. We'd need more information to be able to guide you further.

To illustrate, here's what your current definition of the `ITranslator<E, R>` interface offers, in plain English:

> "I provide a mechanism to translate
>   any record of type `R` into an entity
>   of type `E`, **this mechanism being
>   dependent upon any user-specified type
>   `T`**."

Your `Gens` class, on the other hand, the way it's currently designed, "implements" the above interface like so:

> "I can translate integers to strings.
>   I provide the *illusion* of allowing
>   the user to specify a type to control
>   how this translation is performed, but
>   in fact there is no choice of type.
>   The `MyOtherClass` class is involved
>   somehow; that's all I can say."

From these two descriptions, it's clear that the `Gens` class **is not really doing what the `ITranslator<E, R>` interface guarantees**. Namely, it is not willing to accept a user-specified type for its `ToEntity` method. That's why this code won't compile for you.

Comment: very nice lucid answer. The class does not implement the interface in its true spirit. Hence the error

Answer (score 2):

You must declare a constraint on a generic type.

```
public string ToEntity<T>(int record) where T : MyOtherClass
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>That compiles OK for me in LINQpad. Maybe you have a type named E, R, or T somewhere?</strike>

Ahh I see what you're trying to do... you have MyOtherClass defined as a class somewhere yet you're trying to use it as a type argument in ToEntity. How exactly do you want MyOtherClass involved in ToEntity?

Comment: That code by itself that you pasted is actually valid code and compiles fine. I'm not quite sure what it is you're intending to do with MyOtherClass in your example.